# AWK - Match First 3 Fields, print $6 & $7 from both files on same line

Tags: awk

My two input files have changed and I need to match the first three fields of two files.  When a match is made, I want to print $1 (of which was matched) and $6 and $7 of file1 and $6 and $7 of file two.  The original code was an AWK one liner to match just the first field.

**File1**

```
BSTN-SANJ   BSTN    SANJ    0   0   50  105910
MRFD-SANJ   MRFD    SANJ    0   0   40  69105
NYRK-SANJ   NYRK    SANJ    0   0   30  905010
SANJ-HMRD   SANJ    HMRD    0   0   25  69010
SANJ-NRFK   SANJ    NRFK    0   0   38  61506
```

**File2**

```
BSTN-SANJ   BSTN    SANJ    0   0   45  601251
MRFD-SANJ   MRFD    SANJ    0   0   39  919591
NYRK-SANJ   NYRK    SANJ    0   0   25  690155
```

**Output**

```
BSTN-SANJ   50  105910  45  601251  
MRFD-SANJ   40  69105   39  919591  
NYRK-SANJ   30  905010  25  690155
```

Comment: please include your original "AWK one liner to match just the first field."  in the body of your Q (not as a comment reply!). Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '
    {key = $1 OFS $2 OFS $3} 
    NR == FNR {f2[key] = $6 OFS $7; next} 
    key in f2 {print $1, $6, $7, f2[key]}
' file2 file1
```